# Audio & Light bluetooth device: Pairing only Light functions

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth speaker with LEDs, named Divoom Timebox Svart. When device is scanned from Windows/phone it appears as 2 devices timebox-audio, timebox-light. When I scan from Debian I only see timebox-light. Why don't I see timebox-audio? Pulseaudio is installed. Any ideas?

[image: timebox-light pairs]

Thanks for your time.